# How can I move every other record to correct row and col programmatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I move every other record to correct row and col programmatically?

```
Given:
row1 colA   
row1 colB   
row2 colA   
row2 colB   
    

Desired:    
row1 colA   row1 colB
row2 colA   row2 colB
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Office 365 `WRAPROWS` could help. Formula: `=WRAPROWS(A1:A10,2)`

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm using MS 365 and WRAPROWS doesn't exist for me

Comment: Is your Excel up to date? Function available since Windows: 2208 (Build 15601) version. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wraprows-function-796825f3-975a-4cee-9c84-1bbddf60ade0